# Running Subscription not recognizing Kerberos Certificate Renewal

Tags: ibm-data-replication

We are replicating from IMS (System z) to WebHDFS on Linux and using Kerberos authentication. The Kerberos certificates expire every number of hours and we use the -kinit to renew them. A running subscription does not seem to have the ability to recognize a certificate has been renewed and will abend. The solution is to stop and restart the subscription, which works, but is there any other way without stopping the sub?

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but the way around this is a script using CHCCLP to stop subscriptions, renew the certificate, then restart the subscription. Use a cron job to auto start this script every *n* hours as needed.